# What's the relationship between numbers.Integral and int in builtins module in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie for Python, I am a little confuse of the relationship between numbers.Integral and int in builtins module.

Then my questions are:

1. What the relationship between numbers.Integral and int? Is it similiar with the relationship between Integer and int in Java (Integer is just a wrapper class for int)?
2. When to use numbers.Integral?
   Since none of the types defined in mumbers module can be instantiated, then in what kind of scenarios we need to use these types?

Only one case I know we can use Integral:

```
 # check if x is a integer
 isinstance(x, Integral)
```

From the Python language reference:

> "
>   *numbers.Number  These are created by numeric literals and returned as
>   results by arithmetic operators and
>   arithmetic built-in functions.* "

But it seems the arithmetic operators or arithmetic built-in functions doesn't return a type in numbers. It is still the type in builtins.

```
>>> a,b=123,5
>>> c=a*b
>>> print(c.__class__)
<class 'int'>
>>> d=abs(a)
>>> print(d.__class__)
<class 'int'>
```

I am using Python 3.2a3.

Comment: Just an aside, if you are a python newbie, you would be better off using an official release of Python, rather than an alpha version.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. Since I am a experienced programmer, I think I can handle this.

Comment: There is a line in numbers.py: Integral.register(int), then int is a subclass of Integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you sound like you know Java: `numbers.Integral` defines the "interface" (it's really a generalization of interfaces, called "Abstract Base Class" (ABC)) for integral numbers. It's *not* a concrete type that you can instantiate.

The only builtin type that implements this interface is `int`.

With `isinstance( obj, numbers.Integral)` you can test if `obj` implements a interface:

```
>>> isinstance(3, numbers.Integral)
True
>>> isinstance(3.0, numbers.Integral)
False
>>> isinstance(3+0j, numbers.Integral)
False
```

If you wanted to write a custom class that behaves like a integral number you would inherit from `numbers.Integral` -- or if you wanted to invent a new type of number you could register it there.

Comment: Then can I regard int as the implementation of numbers.Integral since the latter is an interface? How and where can I verify such a relationship? Many thanks.

Comment: "The only builtin type that implements this interface is int. "  It should be int and bool.